# What are modulos and how would I be able to use them to solve questions regarding the last digit of a raised power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponential-function

When given questions like "What is the last digit of the result to 3^56?", I usually look for a recurring pattern involving smaller powers of 3. In this question for example, the recurring pattern for the last digit is 3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7 , 1, 3, 9, ... I use a similar technique when faced with problems such as "What is the remainder when 2^2010 is divided by 7". However, my textbook presents the solution to these problems using modulos of which I am not familiar with and my textbook won't explain them very well. So, could you please introduce me to modulos as well as how they relate to such questions?

Additionally, it would be greatly appreciated if you also explained problems using modulos such as "Find the smallest number which when divided by 3 gives a remainder of of 1; when divided by 4 gives a remainder 2; when divided by 5 gives a remainder of 3; and when divided by 6 gives a remainder of 4.

For the above problem I usually just find the LCM of 3, 4, 5 and 6 which is 60 and then minus 2 = 58.

Thank you so much:)

Comment: You should start by reading Wikipedia's page on [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). In short, we say that $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ if the remainders of $a$ and $b$ when divided by $n$ are the same. The useful part is that this "equality" plays nice with multiplication and addition.

Comment: By the way, the standard approach to the last problem you mention is to apply the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#A_constructive_algorithm_to_find_the_solution).

Comment: show that $3^{16}\equiv 21 \mod 100$